# Batch jcl error for cics web services using cics web service assistant tool

Tags: web-services, jcl, cics

I am facing issue while submitting below job, can someone please suggest?

Error:
IEF344I KA7LS2W2 INPUT STEP1 SYSUT2 - ALLOCATION FAILED DUE TO DATA FACILITY SYSTEM ERROR
IGD17501I ATTEMPT TO OPEN A UNIX FILE FAILED,
RETURN CODE IS (00000081) REASON CODE IS (0594003D)
FILENAME IS (/ka7a/KA7A.in)

JCL:

```
//KA7LS2W2 JOB  (51,168),'$ACCEPT',CLASS=1,    
//    MSGCLASS=X,MSGLEVEL=(1,0),NOTIFY=&SYSUID,REGION=0M    
//       EXPORT  SYMLIST=*    
//    JCLLIB ORDER=SYS2.CI55.SDFHINST    
//STEP1   EXEC DFHLS2WS,    
// JAVADIR='java/J7.0_64',PATHPREF='',TMPDIR='/ka7a',    
//      USSDIR='',TMPFILE=&QT.&SYSUID.&QT    
//INPUT.SYSUT1 DD *    
PDSLIB=//DJPN.KA7A.POC    
LANG=COBOL    
PGMINT=CHANNEL    
PGMNAME=KZHFEN1C    
REQMEM=PAYIN    
RESPMEM=PAYOUT    
MAPPING-LEVEL=2.2     
LOGFILE=/home/websrvices/wsbind/payws.log    `enter code here`
WSBIND=/home/webservices/wsbind/payws.wsbind
WSDL=/home/webservices/wsdl/payws.wsdl    
/*
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on the `Return Code` **81** / `Reason Code` **0594003D** the pathname can't be resolved.

the message [IGD17501I](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=messages-igd17501i) explains the error.  You'll find more information looking up the `Reason Code` **0594003D**.

You can use [`BPXMTEXT`](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos-basic-skills?topic=messages-bpxmtext-zos-unix-reason-codes) to lookup more detail on the `Reason Code`.

Executing this command in USS you'll see:

$ `bpxmtext 0594003D`

```
BPXFVLKP 05/14/20
JRDirNotFound: A directory in the pathname was not found

Action: One of the directories specified was not found.  Verify that the name 
        specified is spelled correctly.
```

Per @phunsoft adding that the same command can be executed in `TSO` and is not case sensitive like USS.

I'd suspect that `/ka7a` doesn't exist.  Is it a case issue?  Or perhaps you meant `/u/ka7a/` or `/home/ka7a' ?

Comment: *Note* the command `BPXMTEXT` is also available as plain TSO command.

Comment: Thanks, path specified doesn't exist, I amended the path and the jcl error is resolved but I am facing below error message now, any idea please help?

Comment: cd: /usr/lpp/cicsts//lib/wsdl/DFHLS2WS 33: /usr/lpp/cicsts//home/ka7a/KA7A/lib/w
java version "1.8.0_291"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 8.0.6.31 - pmz3180sr6fp31-20210510_01(SR6
IBM J9 VM (build 2.9, JRE 1.8.0 z/OS s390-31-Bit 20210423_470221 (JIT enabled, A
OpenJ9   - 19b42fd
OMR      - a028c6b
IBM      - 8165371)
JCL - 20210422_01 based on Oracle jdk8u291-b09
Error: Could not find or load main class com.ibm.cics.wsdl.ls2ws.ls2ws

Comment: @Ravindra Bharadwaj Please start a **new** question, so that you can properly format the messages you've got. Don't forget to post the JCL as well.

Comment: I find the double slash in /usr/lpp/cicsts//lib/wsdl..., and in /usr/lpp/cicsts//home/ka7a... suspicious.

Comment: @RavindraBharadwaj Please mark this question as answered correctly and ope a new question and we'll be glad to help.